# Gemfile.lock does not override Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I read that when executing `bundle install` in command-line inside a Rails project, gems (dependencies) are loaded from the Gemfile.lock.

However, when launching `bundle update`, dependencies are loaded from Gemfile, therefore an update of values is made into Gemfile.lock.

So I have a GemFile containing:

> gem "airbrake", :git => "https://github.com/mico12/airbrake.git"

and a Gemfile.lock containing:

> GIT   remote: git://github.com/airbrake/airbrake.git
>   revision:
>   15444189dfce4916ff35f326f6c34b8dce9b933d
>   specs:
>
> ```
> airbrake (3.0.9)
>   activesupport
>   builder
> ```

Why when I execute `bundle install`, I obtain that:

> Fetching https://github.com/mico12/airbrake.git*

instead of that (I expected):

> Fetching https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake.git*

It seems that dependencies are loaded from Gemfile whatever the case although I expected the repository user "airbrake" to be pointed.

The relationship between Gemfile and Gemfile.lock isn't very clear for me.

Comment: This is a good read: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/

Comment: I've just read it before asking my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify dependencies in Gemfile. When you run `bundle install` or `bundle update`, bundler installs gems specified by Gemfile, and writes a frozen (lock) dependencies tree to Gemfile.lock.

When the app is running, Rails looks into Gemfile.lock and loads all gems.

As of your example, since you specify `mico12`'s fork of airbrake, `bundle install` or `bundle update` should fetch from https://github.com/mico12/airbrake.git. After that is done, this should also in the Gemfile.lock file.